# Symfony2: should a voter check parent entity "permissions" as well?

Tags: symfony, permissions

Let's say I have the following structure: Users have Companies which have Products. To determine if a Product is available, I need to check if the Product, Company and User are all active (and likely other checks).

If I'm working on the voter for Products, should it check to see if the Company and User are active or stick to just checking if Product is active (thus I'd have to do 3 checks in the controller)? If the first option is better, how would you go about doing that – is it possible to call a voter inside a voter?

Comment: You can have reference to user in product and check in voter. Maybe make another table with products id's and active state, and simple listeners if user or company deleted/deactivated change active state to false?

Comment: Voters are usually declared as services so it would be possible to inject one into another. Anyway I don't know if using voters for this kind of business logic is a good idea as you would need to involve a decision strategy to know what to do in the case of abstentions or negative votes

Comment: @xocasdashdash Would you create a separate class/service to do the checking? I'll need to check in views (twig), other services as well as controllers. I'm also not clear why I'd have to deal with abstentions as I'd be checking with another voter directly, unless you're meaning I should be calling isGranted directly inside the product voter (for example).

Comment: I mean that, at least for me, the whole voting authorization system is heavily biased towards authorization not to check, as is your case, availability. Would that availability change depending on the user? I just had a very similar problem last week at work and what we ended up doing was something similar to the way form validation works, we check if an object is "valid" and if not we store violation messages in a validation context. To check validity we check to see if the number of violations is equal to 0.

Comment: Anyways I would recommend you create another service that does validation and call this one instead of using voters. Also I'd recommend to try to eliminate as much logic as you can from your templates and move it to services as much as posible